# Python turtle.Terminator error

Tags: python, python-3.6, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

When i am using turtle module to draw a circle with this simple function:

```
def draw_shape(self):
    canvas = Screen()
    t = Turtle()
    t.circle(self.r)
    canvas.exitonclick()
```

For the first time when i call this function it opens a new window and draw a circle, i click on it to exit and when i try to again call this function from menu in console i got an error:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 136, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 132, in main
    OPTIONS[user_input][1](shapes)
  File "main.py", line 48, in handle_sixth_menu_option
    t = Turtle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 3816, in __init__
    visible=visible)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

Comment: Is your goal to open a new window for every shape? That's a strange use case. Generally, turtle is used continually in one window, drawing multiple shapes. In the normal case, calling `exitonclick`, `done` or `bye` is only done at the very end of the whole app, and you don't call any further turtle methods. [Python Turtle.Terminator even after using exitonclick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534458/) is the canonical for this use case. On the other hand, if you want to intentionally open and close multiple windows, this thread can address that use case.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the turtle module (most reference implementations as of today) uses a class variable called _RUNNING. This becomes false during the exitonclick() method.

Changing your code to below should help.

```
import turtle

def draw_shape(self):
    canvas = Screen()
    turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING=True
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.circle(self.r)
    canvas.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Pretty much the same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70551408/6243352). Best to post in one place and mark a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
def draw_shape(self): 
    import turtle as t
    canvas = Screen() 
    t.circle(self.r)                                                    
    canvas.exitonclick()
```

The reason your code wasn't working was because of the fact that you had already deleted or exited the instance of the turtle in the `def` function already once before by clicking on exit. Hence by using `import turtle as t` you are calling it again and creating a new instance.