# Turtle not responding on Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am struggling to get the Turtle module to respond (change shape, color etc.) whilst using PyCharm. I am following a Udemy course and I believe I am using the correct code to change the attributes but to no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I have attached a screenshot of the code and GUI box.[image]

I believe I have imported the Turtle module correctly and have used the correct syntax to change the shape and color of the turtle. No success so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Turtle.Terminator even after using exitonclick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534458/python-turtle-terminator-even-after-using-exitonclick)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

The `exitonclick` method starts the GUI's mainloop, which means all the lines that come after will not be executed until the GUI is closed.

The solution would be to simply move the `exitonclick` line to the last line of your script:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

aubree = Turtle()
my_screen = Screen()

aubree.shape("turtle")
aubree.color("coral")

my_screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `my_screen.exitonclick()` to the very end of the program.
So, like this:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
aubree = Turtle()
my_screen = Screen()

aubree.shape("turtle")
aubree.color("coral")

my_screen.exitonclick()
```