# Turtle raises turtle. Terminator error in PyCharm and IDLE on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, turtle-graphics

I am using the latest version of Python and still the turtle graphics are not working.

```py
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

timmy = Turtle()

my_screen = Screen()

my_screen.exitonclick()

timmy.shape("turtle")
```

The output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) :
File
"/Users/memyselfandabhi/PycharmProjects/day16-start/main.py", line 10, in <module>
timmy.shape ("turtle")
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/turtle.py", line 2779, in shape
self._update()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python. framework/Versions/3.11/Lib/python3.11/turtle.py", Line 2661, in
_update
self._update_data()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python. framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/turtle.py", line 2647, in
_update_data
self.screen._incrementudc()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/turtle.py", line 1293, in _incrementudc
raise Terminator
turtle. Terminator
```

How can I fix this?

I tried reinstalling PyCharm and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: As well, could you not use an image and use code blocks instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Turtle.Terminator even after using exitonclick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534458/python-turtle-terminator-even-after-using-exitonclick)

Comment: Tip: try to focus on the specific error rather than "doesn't work". If you do a search, you'll see many TerminatorError posts, and all of them have one thing in common: trying to run turtle code after destroying the window. The fact that the error shows up only after clicking is important and worth mentioning in your question. See also [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Run an experiment: try removing code line by line to see if anything changes. After some fiddling, you'll see that removing that last line makes the error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `screen.exitonclick` should be at the end of the file, so it should look like this:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

timmy = Turtle()

my_screen = Screen()

timmy.shape("turtle")

my_screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. That was dumb of me to use **screen.exitonclick** before changing the shape :P