# Getting an error - turtle.terminator on calling a function of simple pendulum second time

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have made a program with turtle to draw a simple pendulum , making it a function so that I can call it multiple times but when I call it second time it gives an error.

Here is the Source code :-

```
import turtle as tu
def pendulum():
    tu.Screen()
    tu.title("SIMPLE PENDULUM")
    tu.begin_fill()
    tu.fillcolor("black")
    tu.fd(70)
    tu.left(90)
    tu.fd(10)
    tu.lt(90)
    tu.fd(70)
    tu.left(90)
    tu.fd(10)
    tu.left(90)
    tu.end_fill()
    tu.penup()
    tu.goto(35,0)
    tu.pendown()
    tu.rt(90)
    tu.fd(100)
    tu.rt(90)
    tu.begin_fill()
    tu.fillcolor("black")
    tu.circle(10)
    tu.end_fill()
    tu.penup()
    tu.goto(35,0)
    tu.lt(45)
    tu.pendown()
    for i in range(10):
        tu.fd(5)
        tu.penup()
        tu.fd(5)
        tu.pendown()
    tu.rt(90)
    tu.circle(10)
    tu.penup()
    tu.goto(35,0)
    tu.lt(180)
    for i in range(10):
        tu.fd(5)
        tu.penup()
        tu.fd(5)
        tu.pendown()
    tu.rt(90)
    tu.circle(10)
    tu.lt(90)
    tu.penup()
    tu.fd(10)
    tu.pendown()
    tu.fd(40)
    tu.lt(135)
    tu.fd(4)
    tu.bk(4)
    tu.lt(90)
    tu.fd(4)
    tu.bk(4)
    tu.rt(45)
    tu.fd(40)
    tu.lt(90)
    tu.fd(40)
    tu.lt(135)
    tu.fd(4)
    tu.bk(4)
    tu.lt(90)
    tu.fd(4)
    tu.bk(4)
    tu.rt(45)
    tu.fd(40)
    tu.rt(135)
    tu.fd(40)
    tu.lt(135)
    tu.fd(4)
    tu.bk(4)
    tu.lt(90)
    tu.fd(4)
    tu.bk(4)
    tu.rt(45)
    tu.fd(40)
    tu.lt(45)
    tu.penup()
    tu.fd(10)
    tu.lt(90)
    tu.rt(90)
    tu.bk(25)
    tu.rt(90)
    tu.pendown()
    tu.circle(130,-86)
    tu.rt(90)
    tu.fd(5)
    tu.bk(10)
    tu.fd(5)
    tu.lt(90)
    tu.circle(130,86)
    tu.lt(90)
    tu.fd(5)
    tu.bk(10)
    tu.penup()
    tu.goto(35,-130)
    tu.pendown()
    tu.rt(45)
    tu.fd(7)
    tu.bk(8)
    tu.penup()
    tu.goto(45,0)
    tu.left(135)
    tu.pendown()
    tu.fd(4)
    tu.bk(4)
    tu.lt(90)
    tu.fd(4)
    tu.bk(4)
    tu.rt(45)
    tu.fd(100)
    tu.lt(135)
    tu.fd(4)
    tu.bk(4)
    tu.lt(90)
    tu.fd(4)
    tu.bk(4)
    tu.penup()
    tu.goto(50,-60)
    tu.write("lenght")
    tu.goto(60,-120)
    tu.write("mg sin(A)",align="left")
    tu.goto(110,-135)
    tu.write("mg",align="left")
    tu.goto(130,-120)
    tu.write("mg cos(A)",align="left")
    tu.goto(118,-105)
    tu.write("A")
    tu.hideturtle()
    tu.done()
```

I have tried to run this program but I am not getting that why it is showing the error in second time not in first time. Please tell me how to resolve it and why the error is raised.
Here is the error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\rudy\TRIAL.py", line 136, in <module>
    pendulum()
  File "D:\rudy\TRIAL.py", line 5, in pendulum
    tu.begin_fill()
  File "<string>", line 5, in begin_fill
turtle.Terminator
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Turtle.Terminator even after using exitonclick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534458/python-turtle-terminator-even-after-using-exitonclick)

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your function, you call `tu.done()`. According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.done), this should be the last statement in the turtle graphics program. Since you still want to run the function a second time, you can instead call `tu.done()` at the very end of your program. For example:

```py
pendulum()
pendulum()
tu.done()
```

By the way, you have a small typo in your function. You swapped the last two letters in the word 'length' ;)